# How to number class objects with an array

Tags: c++, class

I have ran into a problem with C++.

For example I have a class `UNIT`. Is there any way, in main to create it like this -

```
unit[1]( int a, int b);

unit[2]...;

unit[532]...;
```

It would be very easy to work with these, but I haven't found any way to make them with an array. Please help, and thanks!

Comment: You mean something like [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the real problem? Maybe there is a better way to address it.

Comment: Are you asking how to put class instances in an array? You do it like putting anything else in an array.

Comment: Well for example, when creating a class, 
class UNIT[a]    - is not legal. 

Also, when in main, creating an object:
UNIT[a](int a, int b)    - is not legal too.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I have no idea what you are wanting your code to do. It's true that you can't create an object like this: `UNIT[a](int a, int b)` -- But you also can't create an object like this: `@vpn8er$90348v` -- The problem is I have no idea what you would expect either of those things to mean.  Please describe your problem in more detail, and please do it by ammending the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not allow you to initialize the elements of an array in that way. In order to initialize the elements of the array you have to do it after the array has been instantiated.

```
unit units[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    units[i] = unit(/*params*/); /./ assumes unit has a copy assignment operator
```

You can however use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array and initialize it's elements with a default value. I highly recommend using a vector instead of an array as it will manage the memory resources for you, can be resized and provides information such as the number of elements it manages.

```
std::vector<unit>   units(10, unit(/*constructor params*/));
```

The example below shows how to do this and includes a version of `unit` with an appropriate constructor. For your purposes you may need to provide a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct unit
{
    int a_;
    int b_;

    // constructor
    unit(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<unit>   units(10, unit(1, 2));

    for(auto i = 0; i < units.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout
            << "element[" << i
            << "] a_ = " << units[i].a_
            << " b = " << units[i].b_
            << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can change unit array to be of type `UNIT *unit[]` and then call different contructors:

```
class UNIT
{
public:
    UNIT(){ m_x = 0; }
    UNIT(int a){ m_x = a; }
    int m_x;
};

int main()
{
   UNIT* arr[2]; 
   arr[0] = new UNIT();
   arr[1] = new UNIT(2);

   cout<<arr[0]->m_x<<endl;//0
   cout<<arr[1]->m_x<<endl;//2
   delete arr[0];
   delete arr[1];

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your posted answer brings in these errors - 
unit[1] = new unit(0,1);
Where the  [1] = ERROR: expected an identifier
and new = ERROR: initilization with '{....}' expected for aggregate object